# "Aspects" or "respects"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

> In the same respects/aspects, we can say it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, a 'respect' is a way in which we approach something, and an 'aspect' is a way in which something presents itself to us, or is presented to us.  So you can see that the difference is subtle.  As JSBangs has said, the phrase "in some/all respects" is idiomatic, but you can see that the meaning is "in whatever way we approach the issue..."

Answer (score 1):

"Respects".  There are similar things you might say where "aspects" would be appropriate ("some aspects of it are right"), but in the sentence you give, "respects" is the conventional idiom.

Comment: I don't want chaos! :-)  could you make it clear when to use which? what's the difference ?

Comment: @lovespring, language is chaos! Embrace disorder! Flee systematics! ... But seriously, the phrase *in some/all respects* is idiomatic, but it's the only phrase I can think of where the word *respects* is used in this manner. Most of the time *aspects* is more appropriate.